# How can I get t-values and p-values for regression coefficients in numpy.polyfit?

Tags: python, numpy, regression, polynomials, coefficients

I've managed to fit a polynomial to points (x,y) using numpy.polyfit (see examplary code below).

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y'])
df_test['x'] = [1,6,8,9,11,15,18,22,30,32]
df_test['y'] = [7,34,19,21,22,25,26,28,32,44]

degree = 3

weights = np.polyfit(x, y, degree)
model = np.poly1d(weights)
results = smf.ols(formula='y ~ model(x)', data=df_test).fit()

results.summary()
```

The results.summary() function only displays the t- and p-values for the model as a whole:

```
OLS Regression Results

...
    
            coef        std err    t         P>|t|      [0.025  0.975]
Intercept   2.132e-14   5.828      3.66e-15  1.000      -13.440 13.440
model(x)    1.0000      0.216      4.635     0.002      0.502   1.498

...
```

The regression coefficients are stored in the model variable, but without the standard error, t- or p-values.

```
model

poly1d([ 5.13478731e-03, -2.51465697e-01,  3.90999674e+00,  6.02905767e+00])
```

How can I get the accompanying **standard errors & t- and p-values for each coefficient** with numpy?

*Note: A previous post (see below) suggested to use the statsmodels package instead. However, fitting a model there does result in different coefficients for my full data. Is there another way?
[t-values and Pr(>|t|) for coefficients of numpy.polyfit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240995/t-values-and-prt-for-coefficients-of-numpy-polyfit)*

Best, hanpet

Comment: you can use numpy vander or polyvander functions to create the basis functions and use them with statsmodels.

Comment: I checked out the polyvander function and tried to apply it, seems like this works - thanks a lot!!!